# Using own Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I created my own database for my project, but i am having a trouble pushing it in the data/data folder.
I first tested it out on my rooted phone and i successfully pushed the database that i created. 
Now im facing a problem on testing it on a different phone. i get an error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblFirstAid: , while compiling: SELECT faName FROM tblFirstAid
```

I placed my database in the assets folder and it was running fine on my rooted phone. 
 What code would i add for it to copy the file from the assets folder and push it inside the /data/data directory.
I already tried the one reigndesign and I am getting that error.

Here is my DB Helper Class

```
package com.dr.droid.lee;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.http.SslCertificate.DName;
import android.util.Log;

public class DbHelper {

    public static final String Row_id = "_id";
    public static final String Row_Name = "faName";
    public static final String Row_Desc = "faInfo";
    private static final String db_Name = "dbDrDroid";
    private static final String db_Table = "tblFirstAid";
    private static final String db_HTable = "tblHospitals";
    private static final String Row_HosName = "HospitalName";
    private static final String Row_HosAdd = "Address";
    private static final String Row_HosReg = "Region";
    private static final String Row_HosCity = "City";
    private static final String Row_HosContact = "Contact";
    private static final String Row_dName = "dName";
    private static final String Row_dTable = "tblDisease";
    private static final int db_Version = 1;
    private dbhelp ourhelper;
    private static Context ourcontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDB;

    private static class dbhelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public dbhelp(Context context) {
            super(context, db_Name, null, db_Version);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + db_Table + " (" + Row_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + Row_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + Row_Desc + " TEXT NOT NULL)" );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + db_Table);
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }

    public DbHelper (Context c){
        ourcontext= c;
    }

    public DbHelper open(){
        ourhelper = new dbhelp(ourcontext);
        ourDB = ourhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void   close(){
        ourhelper.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFAData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> comments = new ArrayList<String>();
        String [] columns = new String[]{Row_Name};
        Cursor c = ourDB.query(db_Table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(Row_Name);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {          
            comments.add(c.getString(iRow));
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        c.close();
        return comments;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getHData(){
        ArrayList<String>  res = new  ArrayList<String>();
        String [] columns = new String []{Row_HosName};
        Cursor h = ourDB.query(db_HTable, columns, null, null, null, null, Row_HosName);
        int HRow = h.getColumnIndex(Row_HosName);
        h.moveToFirst();
         while (!h.isAfterLast()) {          
                res.add(h.getString(HRow));
                h.moveToNext();
            }

            h.close();
            return res;

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDData(){
        ArrayList<String>  res = new  ArrayList<String>();
        String [] columns = new String []{Row_dName};
        Cursor d = ourDB.query(Row_dTable, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int HRow = d.getColumnIndex(Row_dName);
        d.moveToFirst();
         while (!d.isAfterLast()) {          
                res.add(d.getString(HRow));
                d.moveToNext();
            }

            d.close();
            return res;

    }



}
```

Here is the class that i used from reigndesign

```
package com.dr.droid.lee;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.dr.droid.lee/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "dbDrDroid";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                this.close();
                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Some how i am still getting errors if my i don't push my database in my phone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Comment: Sample project is here http://sdrv.ms/N857Wn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your DB_NAME is not the same to the Database which exists in your assests folder.

If you are following "reigndesign", then check this line:

```
private static String DB_NAME ="myDBName";
```

DB_NAME here is the name of your database. It is assumed that you have a copy of the database in the assets folder. Your DB_NAME must be the same which exists in the assets folder.

OR

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728).

Comment: i have checked it sir. it is the same as the one in my assets folder

Comment: I had it working now sir, thanks for the link that you have posted

Answer (score 0):

When you give it a nonexistent file name, SQLite will happily create a new, empty database.

Ensure that the file names you use for copying and for opening the DB are identical.

Comment: so ill be calling the copy method ryt after the oncreate database method?

Comment: Yes. What are the file names used for copying, and opening?

Comment: dbDrDroid is the file name of the database that i am using, i have edited my post and paste my codes.